# Difference between rings and algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebras

It is clear that, if we forget scalar multiplication, associative algebras reduce to rings. It the resulting ring is unital however, one can recover scalar multiplication $ka:=(k1)a$, for all $k\in\mathbb{F}$, the field where the algebra is defined, and $a$ in the algebra. So what is the difference between unital rings and associative unital algebras?

Comment: You'll have to remind me what $k1$ is defined to be. As far as I can see if one takes $\mathbb{F}_4$ as an $\mathbb{F}_4$ algebra, throws away the algebra structure, then the resulting unital ring can be made into an $\mathbb{F}_4$ algebra in two different ways (swapping the actions of the two $3$-roots of unity.)

Comment: For a ring $R$ and a field $F$ that $R$ is a $F$-algebra means $R$ is a left $F$-module and the $F$-module action commutes with the multiplication of $R$. This is what you need to obtain a ring homomorphism $P(x) \in F[x] \mapsto P(r) \in R$ for all $r \in R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that to define $ka=(k1)\cdot a$, you have to already know what $k1$ is.  If all you have is a ring, then you don't know what $k1$ is yet.  The same (unital) ring can have *different* $\mathbb{F}$-algebra structures, since $k1$ could be defined differently in them.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is this: Algebras have a scalar multiplication defined, rings don't. The fact that the multiplication can be recovered to make some rings into algebras in a canonical way is more or less irrelevant.

Comment: It's rather misleading to call what OP is describing "canonical", though, since it requires you to know what $k1$ is.

Comment: @EricWofsey That is true. I think the only time you have a canonical reconstruction is when $\Bbb F$ is contained in the ring. Or at least a unique or distinguished homomorphism from $\Bbb F$ to the ring.